# Xamarin android App - Changing device language to "he-IL" does not set UICulture

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, localization

I have a Xamarin forms (v5.0.0.1558pre3) android Application on Visual Studio 2019
I want my App to support different languages so I did the following:

1. I have created AppResources.resx for default language resources and AppResources.he-IL.resx with just a resx file for my Hebrew language like so:

[image]

2. I have set the language on the device to Hebrew.
3. I then set all strings to use the resources:

   Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.MonthlyUsage}"

When I launch the application, it still loads the default AppResources.resx values.

[image]

Other languages (like fr-FR) are being set just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think on Android you will need to check the currently set Android locale like so:

```
var locale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
```

There is a thread on the Xamarin Forums describing a similar issue: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74484/app-crashes-when-language-set-to-hebrew

It seems like you will also have to replace `_` with `-` and also seems like `iw_IL` needs to be changed to `he_IL`.

You will have to detect this on startup and adjust the CurrentUICulture accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, exactly what I needed. Works like a charm. So just to clarify, the replacing of the _ to - and the changing of the iw_IL to he-IL needs to be done on the android project. I have done it within the MainActivity OnCreate.